# File Upload using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Sending a file through socket.emit to server

Client Side:

```
jQuery('#file-upload').on('submit', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

var form = jQuery('#fileup')[0].files;
console.log(form[0]);

socket.emit('fileupload', {
    formData: form[0]
}, function () {
    jQuery('[name=message]').val('')
});
```

form[0] =>

```
lastModifiedDate:Fri Jun 01 2018 05:23:36 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
name:"5b10d858e7fea_images.jpg"
size:9346
type:"image/jpeg"
webkitRelativePath:""
```

Server Side:

```
 socket.on('fileupload', (req) => {
console.log(req);
}
```

Prints:

```
<Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff db 00 84 00 09 06 07 13 13 12 15 14 13 13 16 16 15 17 17 20 1a 18 18 18 18 1f 1a 1a 1b ... >
```

How can I receive the file instead and save it?

Comment: It's not good to use socket for sending files.

Comment: Then any alternatives?

Comment: this is how to send file using socket.io and nodejs.  use jquery and nodejs to send the file to the directory. try to get the filename and the then emit it. since the file is now uploaded to directory, try to link up the directory name and filename to where you are outputting the response.  it just very simple logic. i have use it to send images, pdf etc

Answer (score 0):

Generally it's not a good idea to send files through sockets.

You'll want to send it through HTTP with Ajax to an API endpoint that will handle it.